# Radio button em gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicação-web

Bom dia pessoal.

Preciso criar um formulário online que tera questões que seram inseridas diariamente no perfil de cada usuário.  Todas as questões sao armazenadas em um banco de dados junto com as suas alternativas e resposta correta.

Ate ai consigo montar tudo certo trago as questões e monto o gridview com os radios button.  No entanto na hora de salvar as respostas preciso pegar as opções dd cad linha do grid e chegar qual rádio esta selecionado.

Segue o codigo do formulario:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="gridQuestoes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="questao" HeaderText="questao" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="Prioridade" HeaderText="Prioridade" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtSim" runat="server" Text="Sim" GroupName="users"/>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtNao" runat="server" Text="Não" GroupName="users"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGravar" runat="server" Text="GRAVAR" OnClick="btnGravar_Click" />
</form>
```

Codigo utilizado para o preenchimento do GridView

```
BancoDeDados bd = new BancoDeDados();
        List<Modelos.Questoes> lista = bd.listarQuestoes(1);
        List<Quest1> listarQuest = new List<Quest1>();



        foreach (Modelos.Questoes questoes in lista)
        {
            if (questoes.tipo == 1)
            {
                listarQuest.Add(new Quest1()
                {
                    questao = questoes.questao,
                    prioridade = questoes.prioridade
                });                    
            }
        }
        gridQuestoes.DataSource = listarQuest;
        gridQuestoes.DataBind();
```

Em algumas pesquisas fiz esse codigo para verificar mas não esta funcionando

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridQuestoes.Rows)
        {
            BancoDeDados bd = new BancoDeDados();
            RadioButton rb1 = row.FindControl("rbtSim") as RadioButton;
            RadioButton rb2 = row.FindControl("rbtNao") as RadioButton;
            if (rb1.Checked == true)
            {                    
                bd.gravar("Sim");
            }
            else if (rb2.Checked == true)
            {                    
                bd.gravar("Não");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @bigown tem alguma ideia de outra maneira que pode ser feito ou se esta errada esse codigo?

Comment: Não mexo com isto, mas logo aparece alguém pra te ajudar.

Comment: Acho que falta ser inserido no seu gridview OnRowDataBound, pra você manipular o que consta dentro dele...Segue um guia explicando sua função https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.

Consegui resolver meu problema dessa maneira não sei se é o melhor maneira mas esta funcionando se alguem quiser utilizar ou tiver uma outra maneira

adicionei um ação para cada vez que o um dos botões for ativado.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtSim" runat="server" Text="Sim" GroupName="users" OnCheckedChanged="rbtSim_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtNao" runat="server" Text="Não" GroupName="users" OnCheckedChanged="rbtNao_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

e nas ações utilizei essa função

```
 protected void rbtSim_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rbSim = (RadioButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)rbSim.Parent.Parent;

        foreach (Quest1 q in listarQuest)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == q.id)
            {
                q.resp = "Sim";
            }
        }            
    }
```

espero que possa ajudar alguem e se alguem tiver um metodo diferente de resolução.

att